# Name for native English inferiority to French/Latin/Greek

Tags: etymology, sociolinguistics

My question is whether there is a name for the phenomenon, and also if there is a body of literature including popular exposition about it, of which the paragraphs below exhibit examples.

"Nativity" is a fancy word for "birth", and what makes it "fancy" seems to be that it's derived from Latin.  English-speaking people tend to regard words obviously derived from Latin or Greek as more hifalutin than words of Germanic origin.  "Substance" is more dignified than "stuff"; "decay" more formal than "rotting"; "predict" more scientific than "foretell".  When Arthur C. Clarke wanted to make the names of two characters in a story set in the very distant future seem futuristic, he called them Eriston and Etania, which seem like ancient Greek names (Or do they?  I now find something on the web saying "Eriston" is of English origin and means "son of Eric", but I am doubtful).

It seems at least somewhat plausible to explain this by saying that people who spoke Latin and were familiar with books in Greek (maybe especially the New Testament?) brought civilization and literacy to British barbarians.

I have heard that something similar happens in Korea.  Korean names of numbers bigger than 1000 are Chinese words.

I know enough about Swahili to know that it's pretty easy to tell which words in that language are derived from Arabic, and among those are all words that would be known only to literate people and unknown only in non-literate communities.  The word "kitabu", meaning "book" is obviously of Arabic origin, although its way of being used in Swahili is completely adapted to that Bantu language, as seen in the fact that its plural is "vitabu" (it is one of a class of nouns in Swahili whose singular (in most instances) begins with "ki-" and whose plural begins with "vi-").  I don't know whether Swahili-speaking people feel the same way about Arabic-versus-Bantu as English-speaking people do about Latin/Greek-versus-Germanic-or-otherwise-barbarian.

**Is there a name for this phenomenon,** whereby even after centuries of development into erudite thinking, people feel that words that come from formerly more civilized foreigners are more civilized, literate, dignified, or formal than native words?  What other instances of it exist than English and Korean?

Comment: "Is there a name for this phenomenon?" - pretention? cultural hegemony? "What other instances of it exist?" - every language?

Comment: I think this would be a better question if you just kept the final paragraph. The rest seems vaguely like a rant, or at least a bunch of paragraphs of your opinion that aren't necessary to the question. And I reckon @Mitch has it right with 'pretention' (or 'pretentiousness' :-)

Comment: How can an unjustified feeling that one's own language is inferior be called "pretention"?  And is it cultural hegemony when it persists more than a thousand years after the formerly superior culture is..... former?

@RoryAlsop : The paragraphs before the last one comprise a list of _examples_.

Comment: There's probably a shorter way of expressing it than *"the phenomenon whereby even after centuries of development into erudite thinking, people feel that words that come from formerly more civilized foreigners are more civilized, literate, dignified, or formal than native words"*, but I think asking for a **name** for this phenomenon is Too Localised.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: my aside about pretention was meant to convey that  the user of such language might be considered pretentious (if the former culture was held in high esteem), making -others- fell inferior. As to cultural hegemony, I'm using loaded terms. The Roman Empire could still be said to hold great cultural affect on the 'West', just like Arabic culture/language in the Middle east, and Chinese culture in the East and South-East Asia. India affects Chinese and Japanese culturally and linguistically with all its exported Buddhism and associated language.

Comment: I think this has the potential to be a very good question if it is changed to be less about "inferiority" and more focused on the linguistic phenomenon of languages having etymologically distinct classes of vocabulary that speakers are sensitive to. It also might be a better fit for linguistics.se, since OP asks for cross-linguistic examples.

Comment: Your opening premise is overly simplistic - we have words for the "same" thing, idea or action because their are nuances in their meanings.  It is what makes our language so rich and colorful!  I'd hate to be limited to "rot" when "decay" says it so much more eloquently - and it's not the origin but rather the sound of the word and the feel of it coming off my tongue that makes it so wonderful! (pardon the example!) :-)

Comment: Many English speakers would reserve *nativity* for Christmas and the birth of Jesus.

Comment: I'm not saying this to plug my own answer, I'm just genuinely puzzled: why was this considered not a real question? The question can certainly be *improved*, but I was able to identify what OP was asking for and answer it, so...

Comment: I am also puzzled as to why it's considered not a real question.  It is indeed a real question.  A boilerplate notice says "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here."  I would disbelieve anyone's assertion that he can't tell what is being asked.  I don't take the notice to be such an assertion because it's boilerplate.  It's just a bit of abusive sarcasm in this case.

Comment: The term you are looking for seems to be [*(linguistic) prestige*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestige_(sociolinguistics)). If not closed "not a real question" I would have voted to close "general reference".

Comment: Your premise is flawed: Those words may have originated in a foreign language, but they are English words now. Those words were associated with being educated, and still are, because despite centuries having passed, language changes slowly and educated people still used them. And, especially, technical language often resorts to coining new words (or borrowing old ones for new purposes) from Latin or Greek because they need precise meanings, unburdened by centuries of baggage and polysemy. It isn't that "real English" is inferior. It's just how vocabulary changes among educated spearkers.

Comment: @MετάEd: If it turns out to be a real question, you should post 'prestige' as an simple answer

Comment: I just came across this relevant Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratum_(linguistics)

Comment: How in the world is this not a real question—or general reference, for that matter? It is a very well-explained and extremely clear question that most likely does have a specific, authoritative answer (though I am sadly unaware of anything more specific than _lexical stratification_), but there is no way any general reference will be able to tell you that if you don't already know it.

Comment: George Orwell's essay "Politics and the English Language" calls this *pretentious diction*

Comment: @Henry : I think you miss the point. Pretentious diction can happen only as a _result_ of the phenomenon I asked about. It's not the same thing as that phenomenon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Japanese is the classic example of the phenomenon you describe, which in the linguistic literature is sometimes referred to as **lexical classes** or **lexical strata**.

In Japanese, there are three lexical strata:

- Yamato Japanese: words that don't have their origin in borrowing from another language.
- Sino-Japanese: words originating from Chinese, centuries ago. Sino-Japanese words often seem "fancier" or more educated than Yamato Japanese words. As such, this is analogous to the Latinate lexical stratum in English.
- Modern borrowings (from English, Portuguese, etc.)

The three lexical strata in Japanese differ not just in social significance, but also in terms of phonology and morphology (here is a [short article](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/8t55c200#page-1) discussing how).

Similarly, in English, we have at least two meaningfully different lexical strata:

- Germanic (e.g. *birth*)
- Latinate (e.g. *nativity*), which also effectively includes words originating from Greek.

Just as in Japanese, not only is the "non-native" stratum considered more erudite than the native one, there are *grammatical* differences between the strata (although fewer than there are in Japanese). For instance, the suffix *-ate* or *-ation* in English can only directly attach to a Latinate word, e.g. *vary* -> *variation*, but not *bury* -> **buriation*.

Comment: I would say that English effectively has three strata: the base Germanic wordstock, Latinate vocabulary that entered the language a long time ago via French, and modern Greco-Latin scientific vocabulary.

Comment: *Lexical classes* and *lexical strata* also refer very often to other, unrelated phenomena. They are not the obvious answers to the OP's question.

Comment: @MετάEd 'substrate' and 'superstrate' maybe, if there is a conquering culture. But that doesn't apply (I don't think to scientific latin/greek).  Oh, also there's a fourth influx of vocab, erudite (but not technical) terminology in late middle/early modern English (14th-16thc)